# Why I can not use a global parameter in for loop?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I tried use global parameter in code like this:

```
model testModel
  outer parameter Integer par;
  outer Integer var;
equation
  for i in 1:par loop
    var[i] = 5 * i;
  end for;
end testModel;

model test
  inner parameter Integer par = 3;
  inner Integer var[par];
  testModel mod;
end test;

simulate(test)
```

And I got the following error:

> Error: The iteration range 1:par is not a constant or parameter
>   expression

All works fine if not using global parameter:

```
model test
  inner parameter Integer par = 3;
  inner Integer var[par];
  testModel mod(par = par);
end test;
```

How can I use the global parameter in "for", or why  can't I?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
model testModel
  outer parameter Integer par;
  Integer var[par];
equation 
  for i in 1:par loop
    var[i] = 5 * i;
  end for;
end testModel;

model test
  inner parameter Integer par = 3;
  testModel mod;
end test;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in OM:

`[<interactive>:3:3-3:19:writable] Error: Could not evaluate structural parameter (or constant): par which gives dimensions of array: var[par]. Array dimensions must be known at compile time.`
`Error: Error occurred while flattening model test`

Comment: Seems like an OpenModelica issue. You can create a ticket for this in the OpenModelica Trac system: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/newticket

Comment: It works fine in Dymola (tested with Dymola 2015 FD01 and Dymola 2018).